# Does a TD-DFT excitation from a closed-shell determinant only include the alpha electron part?

Tags: density-functional-theory, orca, kohn-sham

From an input in ORCA 5.0.3

```
! PBE 6-31G*
%TDDFT NROOTS
3
END
* xyz  0 1
 H      0.  0.  0.
 H      0.  0.  0.7414
*
```

the output includes

```
STATE  1:  E=   0.549785 au     14.960 eV   120663.8 cm**-1 <S**2> =   0.000000
     0a ->   1a  :     0.986865 (c= -0.99341072)
     0a ->   3a  :     0.013135 (c=  0.11460862)
```

My question is, does the main part (>90%) of the above excitation describe

$$(\sigma_g)_2 \to (\sigma_g)_\beta (\sigma_u)_\alpha \tag{1}\label{1}$$

or

$$(\sigma_g)_2 \to (\sigma_g)_b (\sigma_u)_\alpha + (\sigma_g)_\alpha (\sigma_u)_\beta  \tag{2}\label{2}$$

Or are (1)&(2) equivalent in energy (or some other option entirely)?

(1) is only alpha electron excited; (2) I guess is from two singly occupied orbitals forming a spin adapted wavefunction and will have two Slater determinants. However, spin adaption is mainly from wavefunction based theory (WFT) perspective, not necessarily justified in KS-DFT. But, even a CIS wavefunction can have multiple determinants, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: The TDDFT matrix for closed shell molecules can be blocked into two channels. One for singlets and one for triplets. They both account for a linear combination of the spin up and spin down channel. Not sure about what is implemented in ORCA, but this is usually taken into account automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Would you provide a reference for ` account for a linear combination of the spin up and spin down channel`, thanks.

Comment: Here you can find a discussion on the spin structure of the BSE excitonic matrix, which is the same of TDDFT https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.02266 . For TDDFT you call look for the paper of Casida. I do not have the reference here.